# Полнотекстовый поиск (CONTAINSTABLE) и кавычки в запросе пользователя

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Есть пользовательская форма с полем ввода (TextBox) и вывода (DataGridView) на C#.
В зависимости от необходимости пользователь может изменять тип поиска в приложении - семантический поиск (при этом запускается хранимая процедура в MS SQL Server с FREETEXTTABLE) или более точный к наименованию поиск (запускается процедура CONTAINSTABLE). 
Проблема в том, что при запросе от пользователя - **Знак "Осторожно кабель"**, при семантическом поиске ошибок не возникает, а во втором случае с сервака прилетает вот это - 
[image: Ошибка при использовании CONTAINSTABLE]

Код на стороне приложения -

```
                    //Смотрим выбран ли семантический поиск
                if(cbHoleFind.Checked)
                    {
                        FindMTR editor = new FindMTR();
                        dgvMTR.DataSource = (editor.FindMTRFunc(tbUserText.Text, 1000, cbClass.Text,cbGroup.Text)).Tables[0];
                    }
                else
                    {
                        string usertext;
                        FindMTRoutSemant editor = new FindMTRoutSemant();
                        //Тут проверяем заполнено ли поле Юзертекстом, это для выбора типа SQL запроса
                        if (tbUserText.Text=="")
                        {
                            usertext = "";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            usertext = "\"" + tbUserText.Text +"\"";
                        }

                        dgvMTR.DataSource = (editor.FindMTRFunc(usertext, 1000, cbClass.Text, cbGroup.Text)).Tables[0];
                    }
```

Немного поясню, тут вынужден делать так- **usertext = "\"" + tbUserText.Text +"\"";** поскольку если не брать всё это безобразие в кавычки то при наличии более одного слова в запросе вновь прилетает ошибка о неправильном синтаксисе, при этом в случае с FREETEXTTABLE этого не происходит....
Дальше идёт класс который переводит всё в параметры и отправляет запрос в базу данных, там всё довольно стандартно.
На стороне базы запрос выглядит следующим образом -

```
        SELECT TOP (@kolvo) WITH TIES MTR.Code_MTR AS [Код ТМЦ], MTR.First_Name AS Наименование, OKVED2.OKVED2 AS ОКВЭД,
                  OKPD2.OKPD2 AS ОКПД, [Group].Exact_Name AS Группа, Klass.Exact_class AS Класс, 
                  MTR.Kod_Supplier AS [Код поставщика],  EI.Basis_EI AS ЕИ---, MTR.OL AS ОЛ,
                  --Status.Status_Name AS [Статус строки],KEY_TBL.RANK

    FROM            MTR INNER JOIN
                             EI ON MTR.EI_ID = EI.EI_ID INNER JOIN
                             [Group] ON MTR.Group_MTR_ID = [Group].Group_MTR_ID INNER JOIN
                             Klass ON MTR.Klass_MTR_ID = Klass.Klass_MTR_ID INNER JOIN
                             OKPD2 ON MTR.OKPD2_ID = OKPD2.OKPD2_ID INNER JOIN
                             OKVED2 ON MTR.OKVED2_ID = OKVED2.OKVED2_ID INNER JOIN
                             Status ON MTR.Status_ID = Status.Status_ID INNER JOIN
    CONTAINSTABLE(mtr, First_Name, @name) 
    AS KEY_TBL 
    ON mtr.code_mtr = KEY_TBL .[KEY] 

    ORDER BY KEY_TBL.RANK DESC
```

Кто-нибудь сталкивался? Подскажите как решить.

Код для подключения к БД -

```
   public class FindMTRoutSemant
{

    string connectionString = @"Data Source=*;Database=*;User Id=*;Password=*";

    public DataSet FindMTRFunc(string name, int kolvo, string classGroup, string groupName)
    {
        // название процедуры in SQL_Server
        string sqlExpression = "Find_MTR_outSemant";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {

            //Create a SqlDataAdapter for the Suppliers table.
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlExpression, connection);
            // указываем, что команда представляет хранимую процедуру
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            // параметр для ввода наименования
            SqlParameter nameParam = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@name",
                Value = name
            };
            // добавляем параметр
            command.Parameters.Add(nameParam);
            // параметр для ввода колва выводимых строк
            SqlParameter kolvoParam = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@kolvo",
                Value = kolvo
            };
            command.Parameters.Add(kolvoParam);

            // параметр для ввода классификац группы
            SqlParameter classParam = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@Class",
                Value = classGroup
            };
            command.Parameters.Add(classParam);

            // параметр для ввода производственных групп
            SqlParameter groupParam = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@Group",
                Value = groupName
            };
            command.Parameters.Add(groupParam);

            // Set the SqlDataAdapter's SelectCommand.
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;

            // Fill the DataSet.
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(dataSet);

            return dataSet;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите код запроса к БД. У вас там ADO.NET или что?

Comment: Поправил текст вопроса. Добавил класс подключения к БД.

Comment: Попробуйте в SqlParameter'ах указать DbType

Comment: Кстати, а собачка в ParameterName точно нужна?

Comment: дак кавычки имеют определенный смысл в синтаксисе `contains`. не мудрено, что ошибка получается в итоге.  удаляйте их из строки запроса, перед отправкой, все равно толку от них не будет, как стоп-слова и знаки препинания, они наверное тоже не учитываются, даже если вы их как то заэкранируете и передадите. или нет?

Comment: одинарные кавычки не пробовали поставить? usertext = "'" + tbUserText.Text +"'";

Comment: сдается мне, поскольку вы пишите что "вынужден делать так (добавлять кавычки) поскольку если больше одного слова ..." и т.д. ла-ла-ла, вы не особо вчитывались в [описание аргумента `simple_term` функции `contains()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments)
 А там написано, что одно слово передается просто так, а фраза из более чем одного слова должна заключаться в кавычки. Так что ваше вынужден-иначе-ошибка, как мне кажется, вызвана некоторым недопониманием как это все работает.

Comment: Всем большое спасибо за участие в обсуждении. Принял решение экранировать кавычку как таковую. Сделал это на стороне приложения в C# (Replace). Всё работает.